# DataTables Editor In MVC

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, jquery-datatables-editor

I want to use DataTables Editor but I want full control over the post back rather than letting Editor-Server handle it. Is there a way to do this? I am able to specifiy the url in Ajax on the client side and it does post back to the Controller, the only problem is I cannot figure how to get the data out of the call.
This is the Ajax portion:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax: ({
            url: "/../AnyController/Update",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: 'POST'
        }),
        formOptions: {
            inline: {
                onBlur: true,
                submit: 'all'
            }
        },
        table: "#timetracker",
        fields: [
            {
                label: "Date1:",
                name: "Date1"
            },
            {
                label: "Comment 1:",
                name: "Comment1",
                type: "textarea"
            }
        ]
    });
```

And this is the Contoller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Update(EditorReturnData wtd)
        {
            return Json(wtd);
        }
```

I have tried using a variety of other method signatures but the value of wtd is always null. I have no problem loading the table just by passing Json data, but how to takeover the update process from datatables editor is eluding me.

I have one update. I could not figure out how the Get, Post and Put could all use the same Controller Method and the method takes no parameters, even for the Post and Put. Finally I figured out that Editor is passing the data in the Header and it could be accessed with Request.Body. From there it must be the Datatables dll that is doing the actual updates.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`I have found the best way to do this is to post back from ajax to a different Controller for Post and Put and you can get access to the return data from the HttpRequest body in the following manner.

```
 public ActionResult Rest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            var stream = request.Body;
            string url = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            string newUrl;
            while ((newUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)) != url)
                url = newUrl;
```

I added this code to the RestController from the Datatables Dot Net Core Demo Rest example which can be downloaded from https://editor.datatables.net/

The Ajax looks like this

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: {
        create: {
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/api/rest/create'
        },
        edit: {
            type: 'PUT',
            url:  '/api/rest/edit'
        },
        remove: {
            type: 'DELETE',
            url:  '/api/rest/remove'
        }
    },
```

Comment: For completeness, the returned data looks like the following: action=edit&data[row_43][first_name]=Bruno&data[row_43][last_name]=Nash&data[row_43][position]=Software+Engineer&data[row_43][office]=London&data[row_43][extn]=6222&data[row_43][start_date]=2011-05-03&data[row_43][salary]=163500